# WTForms's InputRequired validator is not working as expected

Tags: python, validation, wtforms

Can someone tell me why `validators.InputRequired()`doesn't let the validation pass through in the following code?

```
from wtforms import Form, PasswordField, BooleanField, StringField,IntegerField, validators

class RegisterReqRules(Form):
    firstname = StringField(
        'Firstname',
        [validators.Length(min=1, max=250),
         validators.InputRequired()])


test= {'firstname': 'joe'}

v = RegisterReqRules(data=test)

v.validate() # <--- returns False
v.errors # <---- {'firstname': ['This field is required.']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing it as `formdata`?

http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/1.0.1/forms.html#wtforms.form.Form.__init___

```
v = RegisterReqRules(formdata=test)
```